# Wildfly CLI to check for existence of resources

Tags: command-line-interface, wildfly

I have the same issue, I tried:

```
if (result.value == true) of /subsystem=datasources/data-source=MyDataSource:read-resource
    data-source remove --name=MyDataSource
#else
  # none   
end-if
```

But it tries every time to remove. Even if the datasource is not available

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your code this way:

```
if (outcome == success) of /subsystem=datasources/data-source=MyDataSource/:read-resource
    /subsystem=datasources/data-source=MyDataSource/:remove
#else
  # none   
end-if
```

Also, you can run any command in CLI and see output. For, example:

1. /subsystem=datasources/:read-resource

   ```
   "outcome" => "success",
   "result" => {
       "data-source" => {"ExampleDS" => undefined},
       "jdbc-driver" => {"h2" => undefined},
       "xa-data-source" => undefined
   }
   ```
2. /subsystem=datasources/data-source=FictiveDataSource/:read-resource

   ```
   "outcome" => "failed",
   "failure-description" => "JBAS014807: Management resource '[
       (\"subsystem\" => \"datasources\"),
       (\"data-source\" => \"FictiveDataSource\") ]' not found",
   "rolled-back" => true
   ```